# Magento 2 How to create checkbox field in widget

Tags: magento2, widget, widgets

I have a custom widget in which I need to create the checkbox field in one of my widget. I am using parameter type as block

Below is my code

1 . widget.xml file

```
<widget class="Sandesh\ProductWidgets\Block\Widget\WhatMakesItFabulous" id="what_makes_it_fabulous">
        <label>What Makes It Fabulous</label>
        <description>what makes it fabulous</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="checkbox" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
                <label translate="true">Select Checkbox</label>
                <block class="Sandesh\ProductWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\CheckBoxChooser" />
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
</widget>
```

2. CheckBoxChooser filer

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement as Element;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;

class CheckBoxChooser extends Template
{

/**
     * @var Template\Context
     */
    private $context;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $data;
    /**
     * @var JsonHelper|null
     */
    private $jsonHelper;
    /**
     * @var DirectoryHelper|null
     */
    private $directoryHelper;
    /**
     * @var Factory
     */
    private $elementFactory;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @param JsonHelper|null $jsonHelper
     * @param DirectoryHelper|null $directoryHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?JsonHelper $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $jsonHelper, $directoryHelper);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->elementFactory = $elementFactory;
    }

    public function prepareElementHtml(Element $element): Element
    {
        $config = $this->_getData('config');
        $input = $this->elementFactory->create('checkbox', ['data' => $element->getData()]);
        $input->setForm($element->getForm());
        $input->setConfig($config);
        $element->setData(
            'after_element_html',
            $input->getElementHtml()
        );
        return $element;
    }
```

Below is my output I can see my checkbox but even after checking and save it wont show it as checked after coming back

[image: Ouput of widget after using this code]